# Searchkick .reindex method not working ( Empty results)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Hello does anyone is really friendly with searchkick ( elastic search) ? 
I got a situation where when i want to reindex my model with Model.reindex it return me :

```
> `irb(main):001:0> Offer.reindex D, [2017-10-18T12:11:54.141503 #4]
> DEBUG -- :   Offer Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "offers".* FROM "offers"
> ORDER BY "offers"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]] D,
> [2017-10-18T12:11:54.241929 #4] DEBUG -- :   Offer Import (71.7ms) 
> {"count":32}
> => true
```

But when i do my search request it return me nothing, before it was working very well until now without doing anything.

Here are the last logs of searchkick add-on

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception",
"reason":"no such index",   "resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"offers_production","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"offers_production"}],
"type":"index_not_found_exception",
"reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias",
"resource.id":"offers_production","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"offers_production"},"status":404}
```

Thank you in advance for your help .. 
If u need any more informations that i haven't shared, please ask me !

Joé

Comment: can you post your query search?

Comment: This ? 
`domain.com/offers/search?title=bla`

Comment: your query search, something like `Offer.search('*', where: {...})`

Comment: Anyway, the problem is with elasticsearch. I tried something like this in the past https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-2-2-index-not-found-exception-logstash/42929/4